# How to split an image in halves by using only scikit and skimage

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to develop an algorithm to determine how symmetrical a picture of a mole would be when processing the image. I have been able to read the picture, convert it from rgb to grayscale, convert grayscale to binary. With the binary image, by using remove small holes and remove small objects, I created a new variable called img_blob that I would then use to analyze how symmetrical the mole would be by using area, perimeter and axes parts from the regionprops function from meas on skimage. To do this, I need to be able to split the blob I create into halves, vertically and horizontally and compare the two sides which is what I need help on. I am trying to do this by mostly using skimage and matplotlib, so nothing from the PIL library. I would like to be able to split my blob into halves which I can assign to a new variable and do the processing of the individual halves from there comparing the top half to the bottom half and the right half to the left half.

So far this is the code I have:

```
IMG_NAME = "first_mole.png"
img = mpimg.imread(IMG_NAME) #read image

img_gray = rgb2gray(img) #grayscale image

#grayscale image
histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(img_gray, bins=256, range=(0, 1))

#Binary image 
thres = skimage.filters.threshold_otsu(img_gray) 
img_binary = (img_gray < thres)

#Removing holes and dots from binary image to better process it
img_binary = morph.remove_small_objects(img_binary, min_size=64)
img_blob = morph.remove_small_holes(img_binary, area_threshold=64)

plt.imshow(img_blob, cmap='gray')
plt.title("Processed Blob")
plt.show()

ang = -things.orientation * 90 / (pi/2) #used  in angle parameter to rotate image vertically

#Plotting rotated image
img_blob = transform.rotate(img_blob, ang)
plt.imshow(img_blob, cmap='gray')
plt.title("Rotated Blob")
plt.show()
```

This is the original photo trying to be processed
[image]

This is the binary image of the photo plotted on python
[image]

This is the rotated binary image to be used for processing (the one I'm trying to split in halves)
[image]

Comment: if the image is a numpy array, use indexing, if it is in HWC format you can do something like `image[:int(height/2)]` or `image[:,:int(width/2)]` there is no need to rotate the image.

Comment: Comparing the image to the rotated image should tell you all you need to know about symmetry.